# Reading zip files using fread

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to call a zip file using fread as like this

```
data<-("www/608.zip")

test<- fread('gunzip -cq data')
```

It showed this error `does not exist or is non-readable`

But it will work if I call

```
test<- fread('gunzip -cq www/608.zip')
```

On my script each time value of data will change so I used If command for choosing data as like this

```
    data<-reactive({
    if (input$list == 'all') 
    { 
    "www/6.zip"
     }
    else{
    if (input$list == 'hkj')
     {
    "www/6.zip"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work as follows:

```
data <- "www/608.zip"
test <- fread(cmd = paste("gunzip -cq", data))
```

i.e. you have to create a command string with [`paste()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) first and then pass it as `cmd` argument to `fread()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the file path you can use `paste0` to create the string

```
data <- "www/608.zip"
test <- fread(cmd = paste0("gunzip -cq ", data))
```

`fread` [suggest](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1116--19-sep-2018) to use cmd argument for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `glue`

```
data <- "www/608.zip"
fread(cmd = glue::glue("gunzip -cq {data}"))
```